# What is imported using the Gjs imports statement?

Tags: linux, gnome, gjs

If I'm looking at Gjs code and see this line near the beginning:

```
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;
```

How can I know what methods, constants, events, etc. are on 'Gio' (without doing a Google search)? Is there a file somewhere on my installation that contains that information?

Obviously I'm asking for any 'imports' statement, not Gio specifically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some of imports statements import other javascript files:

- `imports.ui.*` -> `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/*`
- `imports.misc.*` -> `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/misc/*`
- `imports.[cairo, dbus, format, gettext, jsUnit, lang, promise, signals]` -> `/usr/share/gjs-1.0/`

For the `imports.gi` imports, Gnome Introspection is used to allow gjs to use C library.
So to get informations about those libraries I suggest you to look at the Gnome reference manuals:

- [Gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/)
- [Gtk](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/)
- [St](https://developer.gnome.org/st/stable/)

But to conclude, there is a huge lack of documentation and examples. That makes difficult to develop with gjs.

UPDATE
Here other useful links:

- [Seed documentation](http://www.roojs.com/seed/gir-1.2-gtk-3.0/gjs/index.html) (seed is another javascript implementation for GNOME)
- [Gjs exemples](https://wiki.gnome.org/Gjs)

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I'm finding it incredibly difficult to develop with gjs.

As for the links you provided, I found those but it's not always obvious what the "C" function names (and parameters) are vs what they are in gjs - which is why I'm now using the instructions in the blog I posted to get the actual gjs documentation.

Comment: You're right, the most difficult is to find the conversion from the C statement to the gjs one.

Comment: For things under imports.gi, there is nowadays https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/ that is quite ok for figuring out what is what. For general rules on how to map C documentation to equivalent Gjs there's https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Gjs/Mapping (useful for GObject Intrespection libraries not included in the gcampana docs).

Comment: You can also add entries to the search path: `imports.searchPath.push("/.../mymodule")` Files (and folders) under /.../mymodule will be importable by `imports.name_of_file`

Comment: Would you please give us the new link for this dead link : St => https://developer.gnome.org/st/stable/

Answer (score 4):

Since I got no answers I kept searching online and found this excellent blog post on how to generate HTML-formatted documentation from typelib files (such as Gio-2.0.typelib):

http://mathematicalcoffee.blogspot.com/2012/09/developing-gnome-shell-extensions_6.html

Comment: Not exactly an answer to this question, but linking to it anyway for the sheer quantity of hard-to-find information:

GNOME shell: Javascript Source Documentation (extensions development)
http://mathematicalcoffee.blogspot.com/2012/09/gnome-shell-javascript-source.html#fileUtils